# Missing "gcc" error when trying to deploy a flask app with requirements.txt to Azure Web App from VSCode

Tags: python, gcc, pip, azure-web-app-service

From within VSCode, using the Azure web service extension, I can deploy a Hello-World flask app successfully to my Azure web app (linux, python 3.6 stack).

When I try to deploy my real flask app (with dependencies listed in a requirements.txt) file, and I specify "pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt" as the web app "startup command" in the Azure portal, browsing the web app page gives an "Application Error".

The log for my web app shows the startup code failing when trying to build "psutil" due to the error **unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory**.

When the above failed, I also tried using "wheels" as part of my deployment as described here (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/29/install-native-python-modules-on-azure-web-apps-api-apps/), but that didn't seem to change anything (same 'missing gcc' error).

Is this the correct way to deploy a flask app with python library dependencies from VSCode?  I would expect that the deployment process would automatically process the requirements.txt (without having to specify the startup command) and I would expect it to be able to install the python libraries without error.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you were using Azure WebApp for Linux based on Docker Container, the MSDN blog [`Install Python Modules on Azure App Services`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/29/install-native-python-modules-on-azure-web-apps-api-apps/) for Azure WebApp for Windows is not useful for your issue.

So for your issue of missing `gcc` error, per my experience, the solution to fix it is to configure a custom Linux container which had been pre-installed the gcc tool-chains and then to deploy your app into it from VS Code.

As references, please try to follow the documents below.

1. [Configure a custom Linux container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container) . To install the `gcc` toolchains in a custom docker image via change the Docker file like install `openssh` as the section [`Enable SSH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh) said.
2. [Deploy to Azure using Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker) from VS Code with Azure App Service extension.